# Architecture for getting data from Api

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, architecture

I'm making a project and here's my solution organization:

```
Core - Entities, Interface's etc..
Data - Repositories, Context's
Services - Bussiness logic
Api - Restful api
Web - Presentation
```

Now I want to make registration in my Web project. Data (email, password, etc) will be sent to my Api. Also Web project will get all data from my Api. I want to ask where I should make Api access logic? In Web project controllers, Data project or make class in my Web project to access Api? Maybe you'll guys suggest some approach?

Comment: Suggesting that "my Api" is an API of another App which must be called from "my Web project" it's a standard solution to create special one level for ecnapsualting of communication with other systems. It is often placed at the same hierarchy level as the Data\DAL level. But your question is not clear.

Comment: my Api is in the same solution

Comment: API is a too general notion. If you are using asp.net mvc than controllers (Web project) itself provide API for your app's clients. Thus it's not clear what you mean talking about "Web project will get all data from my Api." If your Web project as a set of controllers, provides API for clients, than, obviously, logic to access your API must be implemented on client-side. I think you a bit misunderstand some notions.

Answer (score 0):

Web project is ASP.NET MVC and Api project is ASP.NET MVC Web Api project. I'll call user will input data (username, password) i'll pass that data to Api project and it will do the work. I want to make that user could register to API using GUI. User will input email, password etc and the he'll get access token from API.